# Style.display block/none problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was planning on making a personal project with JavaScript until I encountered a problem. I have a table that's "Invisible" with css "`style.display=none`" but when I try to make it "visible" I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

JavaScript Code below:

```
    function attack(){
        document.getElementById("list").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
    }
    function fire(){    
        var y=document.getElementById("message");   
        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        var z=document.getElementById("att");
        x.innerHTML=3;
   }
function disappear(){
    document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";   
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<center>Wild SlayerZach has appeared.</center>";
}
```

HTML below:

```
<body onload="disappear()">
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td><img id="SHP" src="Hp/HPSlayerzach/hp2.png"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src="characters/slayerzach/slayerzach.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
            <td ><img id="att" src="backgrounds/spacer1.png"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img align="right" src="characters/fighterdan13/fighterDan13.gif"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img id="FHP" src="hp/HPFighterdan13/hp1.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="message" colspan="2" background="backgrounds/backgroundText.png">
                <center><table border="0" id="list">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center><a onclick="fire()">FIRE</a></center></td>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>LIGHTNING</center></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>WATER</center></td>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>EARTH</center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><table border="0" background="backgrounds/backgroundmenu.png">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button id="butAtt" onclick="attack()">Attack</button></td>
                        <td><button id="butItems" disabled>Items</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><center><button id="butRun" style="width:110px; height:25px;" disabled>Run</button><center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>      
</body>
```

Comment: The error indicates that `document.getElementById("list")` is not returning the element, but instead a null value. Can you make a fiddle/demo? If the element exists with that ID, it should be fine, so I'm not immediately seeing an issue

Comment: It's just when I run it, the `onload` works. So my table is "invisible" but when click on my "Attack" button that's when the error comes in.

Comment: i think the error is with document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";

Comment: element 'message' is missing in your code

Comment: It is in there. It's right under body.

Comment: `<td>` tag outside `<table>` not good ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UD8UG/1/)

**HTML**

```
     <body onload="disappear()">
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td><img id="SHP" src="Hp/HPSlayerzach/hp2.png"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src="characters/slayerzach/slayerzach.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
            <td ><img id="att" src="backgrounds/spacer1.png"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img align="right" src="characters/fighterdan13/fighterDan13.gif"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><img id="FHP" src="hp/HPFighterdan13/hp1.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" background="backgrounds/backgroundText.png">
                <center><table border="0" id="list">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center><a onclick="fire()">FIRE</a></center></td>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>LIGHTNING</center></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>WATER</center></td>
                        <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>EARTH</center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>
                <div id="message"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><table border="0" background="backgrounds/backgroundmenu.png">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button id="butAtt" onclick="attack()">Attack</button></td>
                        <td><button id="butItems" disabled>Items</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><center><button id="butRun" style="width:110px; height:25px;" disabled>Run</button><center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>      
</body>
```

**CODE**

```
    function attack(){
        document.getElementById("list").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
    }
    function fire(){    
        var y=document.getElementById("message");   
        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        var z=document.getElementById("att");
        x.innerHTML=3;
   }
function disappear(){
    document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";   
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<center>Wild SlayerZach has appeared.</center>";
}
```

Problem was you replace the message innerhtml on disappear.it remove the table which have id list.so i create div with id message inside the td and remove message id from the td.

Comment: it says > fire is not defined in firebug

Comment: @srk yes it dont have function called fire.am just fix what he ask

Comment: That wont work due to `<td id="message" colspan="2" background="backgrounds/backgroundText.png">` is part of a different table. Should I copy/past the code as a whole?

Comment: @user3268382 paste full html

Comment: Problem was you replace the message innerhtml on disappear.so it remove the table which have id list

Answer (score 0):

The error is with 'document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";'.There is no element by Id 'message'.Remove it,it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The other best practice is to always check whether the element exists in the DOM:

something like below:

```
    if(document.getElementById("message")){ 
        document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<center>Wild SlayerZach has appeared</center>";
    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";` works fine in the "onload".

It's when I click the "attack" button I get the error

Comment: Yes onload you first set it to display:none and when you click on attack the element is not found in the DOM to set it to display: block, So this element/object is never found in DOM as it was set to display:none

Comment: May I please recommend you to use Jquery show(); hide(); or toggle function instead.

Answer (score 0):

try dont use `display:none` through Javascript but from css, here is the example from your code i modify it a bit on link below

HTML Code

```
<body>
<td id="message" colspan="2" background="backgrounds/backgroundText.png" >
<table border="0" id="list" style="display:none;">
<tr>
   <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center><a onclick="fire()">FIRE</a></center></td>
   <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>LIGHTNING</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>WATER</center></td>
    <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:15px"><center>EARTH</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="butAtt" onclick="attack()">Attack</button>
```

Javascript

```
function attack(){
    document.getElementById("list").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeansBolong/sdqT2/)